# JQuery Redirect to URL after specified time

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

Is there a way to use JQuery to redirect to a specific URL after a give time period?

Comment: You should accept the correct answer...

Comment: If you want cross-browser and seo support: [redirect generator](http://insider.zone/tools/client-side-url-redirect-generator/)

Answer (score 123):

You could use the [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) function:

```
// Your delay in milliseconds
var delay = 1000; 
setTimeout(function(){ window.location = URL; }, delay);
```

Answer (score 59):

You don't really need jQuery for this. You could do it with plain javascript using the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) method:

```
// redirect to google after 5 seconds
window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 14):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.setInterval(function() {
    var timeLeft    = $("#timeLeft").html();
        if(eval(timeLeft) == 0) {
                window.location= ("http://www.technicalkeeda.com");
        } else {
            $("#timeLeft").html(eval(timeLeft)- eval(1));
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I would discourage the use of `eval()` as it has many dangerous consequences. Instead I would recommend using `parseInt()`.

Comment: The only problem with this is that if the redirect doesn't happen quickly it keeps redirecting and never gets to the target page

Answer (score 13):

You can use

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      setTimeout(function() {
       window.location.href = "http://test.example.com/;"
      }, 5000);
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

just use:

```
setTimeout("window.location.href='yoururl';",4000);
```

..where the '4000' is m.second

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the solution is to use [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp), like this:

```
var delay = 10000;
var url = "https://stackoverflow.com";
var timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = url;
}, delay);
```

note that the result was stored into `timeoutID`. If, for whatever reason you need to cancel the order, you just need to call

```
clearTimeout(timeoutID);
```

Answer (score 3):

I have made a simple demo that prompts for X number of seconds and redirects to set url. If you don't want to wait until the end of the count, just click on the counter to redirect with no time.
Simple counter that will count down while pulsing time in the midle of the page. 
You can run it onclick or while some page is loaded.

**[LIVE DEMO ONLOAD](https://jsfiddle.net/GlupiJas/r29r1h0c/)**

**[LIVE DEMO ONCLICK](https://jsfiddle.net/GlupiJas/k6prgpbw/)**

I also made github repo for this:
https://github.com/GlupiJas/redirect-counter-plugin

**JS CODE EXAMPLE:**

```
// FUNCTION CODE
function gjCountAndRedirect(secounds, url)
{

        $('#gj-counter-num').text(secounds);

        $('#gj-counter-box').show();

    var interval = setInterval(function()
    {

        secounds = secounds - 1;

        $('#gj-counter-num').text(secounds);

        if(secounds == 0)
        {

            clearInterval(interval);
            window.location = url;
            $('#gj-counter-box').hide();

        }

    }, 1000);

    $('#gj-counter-box').click(function() //comment it out -if you dont want to allo count skipping
    {
        clearInterval(interval);
        window.location = url;

    });
}

// USE EXAMPLE
$(document).ready(function() {
    //var
    var gjCountAndRedirectStatus = false; //prevent from seting multiple Interval

    //call
    $('h1').click(function(){
        if(gjCountAndRedirectStatus == false)
        {
            gjCountAndRedirect(10, document.URL);
            gjCountAndRedirectStatus = true;
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use setTimeout function with either of the following

```
// simulates similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");

// simulates similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";

setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
}, 1000)
```

source:
https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-redirect-web-page/

Comment: How does this solve the second part of the question (_...after a give time period_)?

Comment: Updated answer with setTimeout function

Answer (score 1):

This is improved @Vicky solution - it has clearInterval() added so it prevents a loop of reloading if the redirect takes too long:

```
                            $(document).ready(function () {
                                var myTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
                                    var timeLeft = $("#countdown").html();
                                    if (eval(timeLeft) == 0) {
                                        console.log('Now redirecting');
                                        clearInterval(myTimer);
                                        window.location = ("@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(redirectUrl))");
                                    } else {
                                        $("#countdown").html(eval(timeLeft) - eval(1));
                                    }
                                }, 1000);
                            });
```