# MVC redirect to another page after a four second pause

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm relatively new to MVC, but I have a problem:

Currently, when a user signs into our site for the first time, they are redirected to a change password page; they must change their password before they can access any of the main functionality of the site. After they change their password successfully though, I want to show my custom "Password successfully changed" message on the change password page; I currently do this. After I display my custom message on my change password page, I want to wait a few seconds and then redirect them to the home page.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
//User successfully changes password on ChangePassword page

return View(); //This keeps them on the ChangePassword page and shows the success message

//Wait five seconds on ChangePassword page

//Redirecttoaction("Index", "Home");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use JavaScript window.location.href.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276677/jquery-redirect-to-url-after-specified-time

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You wont be able to do that on the server side, you'll have to use javascript. You can use

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
window.location.href='your URL';
}, 4000);
```

Comment: yes and ajax to send the data and recieve the result if it was success or not

Comment: You could also diplay a timer with jquery

Answer (score 7):

Another method you could consider is an old school meta-refresh

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4; url=http://example.com/">
```

Which you could control with a property on your model or a value in the ViewBag

```
@if(Model.DoRedirect) {
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4; url=http://example.com/">
}
```

Since this needs to be in the header, you might need to put a header "section" in your _layout

```
<head>
    ...
    @RenderSection("header", required: false)
</head>
```

Which you can then use in your view like

```
@section header
    @if(Model.DoRedirect) {
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4; url=http://example.com/">
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The "wait 4 seconds" part happens client-side, so the resulting redirect should also be client-side.  You can redirect in JavaScript after 4 seconds with something like this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.replace('@Url.Action("Index", "Home"')
}, 4000);
```

Note the use of the `Url.Action()` helper method to inject the resulting URL into the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do this on the client as your server processing ends at return View(); for the request. You have a few options on the client, for example, use a javacript timer and after so many miliseconds invoke your next action.

```
function onTimerElapsed(){
    window.location='@Url.Action("SomeAction","SomeController")';
}
```