# Single Google Analytics for multiple domains with a single landing page?

Tags: google-analytics, hosting

I have a GoDadddy account with hosting and domains (I know,,, GoDaddy sucks...), but I currently have multiple domains pointing to the same folder, and it has a single PHP page with the GA tracking code for a single domain. Because all the domains point to the same folder in the hosting, I see all visits for all domains as they are for a single domain in the GA panel. Is there a way to find out which visits come from what domain?

Comment: Select hostname as a second dimension if you reports or create a filter for your data view that includes the hostname in the page url (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012243?hl=en, will not work for data already collected). Not the best question for SO I guess,  since it does not involve any coding.

Comment: I was reviewing my answers and found that this was not marked as completed. If this answered your question, could you please mark it as the solution?

Comment: But you did not answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Currently GoDaddy has 3 hosting plans. The only two that allows you to have multiple domains are Deluxe and Ultimate.

How you conduct the implementation will affect the way GA reports the data. Now I am going to make the assumption that you have access to all the domains you said you currently have.

This is what you need to do to track your traffic

1. Check if you are allowed to have multiple Domains.
2. If Domains are not registered in Godaddy, make sure that all domains and the Primary Domain are pointing to Godaddy DNS or nameservers.
3. Add all domains as 'addons' domains or additional domains to your hosting account making sure you have a separate folder for each domain.
4. In each Domain Folder, create a basic HTML (index.html) page and paste the Google Analytic code in the Head section. Repeat this for every Domain.
5. Create 301 redirects to your PHP page that has the same Google Analytic code that you used for all the pages in 4.

IN Google Analytics Report you should be able to see all the redirected domains show as 'referral'.

Note: Sometimes the redirect might take place before the GA script is loaded and therefore you will not be able to track the referral. If you really care about absolutely all the referral traffic data, I will recommend you to not use 301 redirect but let the pages load and place a [JavaScript redirect with a 5 second delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276677/jquery-redirect-to-url-after-specified-time).